# Does GRPC have a Channel that can be used for testing?

Tags: java, grpc

I'd like to create a simple test but with RPC within the same JVM.

What I was thinking was something like

```java
@Test
void foo() {
    Channel channel = new SomeMagicalObject(new MySystemImpl());
    SystemStub stub =  SystemGrpc.newStub(channel);

    var ret = stub.doSomething(...)
    assertThat(ret).isTrue();
}
```

I was wondering if there's something already built that implements `Channel` that takes in a GRPC server implementation.  That way I avoid having to run Netty and manage ports etc. Like this...

```
private static Server server;
private static Channel channel;

@BeforeAll
@SneakyThrows
static void setupServer() {
    server = ServerBuilder.forPort(0)
            .addService(new MySystemImpl())
            .build()
            .start();
    channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", server.getPort())
            .usePlaintext()
            .build();

}

@AfterAll
@SneakyThrows
static void teardownServer() {
    server
            .shutdown()
            .awaitTermination();
}
```

Comment: are you doing unit or integration test? [InProcessServerBuilder maybe helps](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/test/java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldServerTest.java)

Comment: yup that's what I needed. you want to write a full answer or shall I?

Comment: i think you're the right one to write it. i'm just seaching something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The InProcess transport is what you want. It is a full-fledged transport, but uses method calls and some tricks to avoid message serialization. It is ideally suited to testing, but is also production-worthy. When used with `directExecutor()`, tests can be deterministic. InProcess transport is used in the examples. See [HelloWorldServerTest](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/test/java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldServerTest.java) for one usage.

```java
private static Server server;
private static Channel channel;

@BeforeAll
@SneakyThrows
static void setupServer() {
    // This code, except for the server.start(),
    // could be moved to the declarations above.
    server = InProcessServerBuilder.forName("test-name")
            .directExecutor()
            .addService(new MySystemImpl())
            .build()
            .start();
    channel = InProcessChannelBuilder.forName("test-name")
            .directExecutor()
            .build();
}

@AfterAll
@SneakyThrows
static void teardownServer() {
    server.shutdownNow();
    channel.shutdownNow();

    // Useful if you are worried about test
    // code continuing to run after the test is
    // considered complete. For a static usage,
    // probably not necessary.
    server.awaitTermination(1, SECONDS);
    channel.awaitTermination(1, SECONDS);
}
```