# How to access a testing gRPC server with ip and port

Tags: java, spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

I want to write a unit test for our production code.

I've read this thead: [Does GRPC have a Channel that can be used for testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71059894/does-grpc-have-a-channel-that-can-be-used-for-testing)

and everything looks simple.

The problem is that I cannot inject the generated test channel at runtime like explained here: https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/inprocess/InProcessServerBuilder.html

The channel is created internally in our production code like this:

```
protected ManagedChannel getChannel(ApplicationInstanceInfo instanceInfo) {
    return ManagedChannelBuilder
        .forAddress(instanceInfo.getHost(), instanceInfo.getPort())
        .usePlaintext()
        .build();
}
```

That means that I need a way to access the test server/channel through host and port. Is there a way to do this?

We use Spring Boot.